# Bootstrap 3 - Image always same height as containing row

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap 3 to setup a layout, and am having issues with sizing of images.  I have one image in one column, and then 4 images in another column to the right of it, in a 4x4 grid.  I would like the first image to always maintain the same height of the other 4, so things are flush at the bottom.

https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/

```
<div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="row no-gutter">


        <div class="col-md-6">
            <img src="http://www.lightswitchcreative.ca/clients/poole/images/image1.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive" style="border-right: 2px solid #fff;" />
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6">

             <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <img src="http://www.lightswitchcreative.ca/clients/poole/images/image5.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive" style="border: 1px solid #fff;" />
                    <img src="http://www.lightswitchcreative.ca/clients/poole/images/image4.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive" style="border: 1px solid #fff;" />
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <img src="http://www.lightswitchcreative.ca/clients/poole/images/image3.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive" style="border: 1px solid #fff;" />
                    <img src="http://www.lightswitchcreative.ca/clients/poole/images/image2.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive" style="border: 1px solid #fff;" />
                </div>

             </div>

        </div>


   </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: I guess that you should use table for the image "grid"

Answer (score 0):

This is the [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/8054/) What I did basically was make your div (column div) fit in the row then made the lone image on the left fit exactly in the col with same height and width. the table-display allows your row and column to have the same height, in the image I added a height of 100%

Html

```
<div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="row no-gutter match-to-row">
     <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 match-to-col">
            <img src="http://www.lightswitchcreative.ca/clients/poole/images/image1.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive" style="border-right: 2px solid #fff; height:100% !important;" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 match-to-col">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <img src="http://www.lightswitchcreative.ca/clients/poole/images/image5.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive" style="border: 1px solid #fff;" />
                    <img src="http://www.lightswitchcreative.ca/clients/poole/images/image4.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive" style="border: 1px solid #fff;" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <img src="http://www.lightswitchcreative.ca/clients/poole/images/image3.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive" style="border: 1px solid #fff;" />
                    <img src="http://www.lightswitchcreative.ca/clients/poole/images/image2.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive" style="border: 1px solid #fff;" />

             </div>

       </div>


   </div>
   </div>
```

css

```
body {
    margin: 10px;
}
.match-to-row{
    display: table;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.match-to-col{
    display: table-cell;
    float: none;
}
```

Comment: The problem here is that the row no longer spans to the width of the browser.  I need everything to still be responsive when the browser is resized.   I wasn't able to view the JSFiddle link you provided,  It seemed to just go to a default fiddle.

Comment: you problem comes on the extra small screen i believe. Am I right?

Comment: No, it's the opposite actually.  If I go to full screen with the browser, that row of images no longer takes up the full width of the page.  I need the layout to maintain a responsive layout.

Comment: Also if I shrink to a small width, the larger image does not fill the fill height of that column either.  Big whitespace above it.

Comment: you need the layout to be the same on every screen? what do you mean by "I need the layout to maintain responsive layout?"

Comment: Well with the way I had it setup coming into this question, the images always filled the entire width of the screen.  Using your solution they no longer do this.